# Male equivalent of "Vulva"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word that means "male external genitals"?.

Would "vulvo" make the most sense if no word exists?

*Vulva* refers in English to external female genitals, though in origin it is the Latin word for ‘womb’, which is an **internal** female genital. So it doesn't make much sense to keep the original meaning at this point since the root word now means "external genitals as specified by the gender suffix".

Any other ideas for a word?

Comment: I think they use "twig and berries" in England, (somebody check me...) but in the US the common words are: *package* and *junk*.  If you need to be more formal, you can just say "genitals" - since they're all hanging out there, there's no need to differentiate between internal and external.

Comment: *genitals* would seem to encompass everything external for a man.  As @Oldbag was also writing, there's nothing inside.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the ‘root word’ (not sure if you’re talking about Latin or English here) now means “external genitals as specified by the gender suffix”? The only productive gender suffixes that English has are borrowed feminisers like _-ess_ and _-ette_, and _vulva_ has none of those. It’s simply a word that, in English, happens to end in an a, and refers specifically to the _female_ external genitalia. (I’m not aware of a word that refers specifically to the male external genitalia, no; _pudenda_ can be used for both genders.)

Comment: @Oldbag and Steve: Not true. Males have internal genitalia as well (the prostate, for example).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Technically correct. But since the prostate is the only part of the male genitalia contained within the "trunk" of the body, wouldn't "prostate" suffice? I think "genitals" usually refers to the swinging parts, if the prostate is included I believe the whole shebang is called: the *uro-genital system*. Kudos for "pudenda".

Comment: @Oldbag There are other bits as well, though with more obscure names. In common parlance, I would assume _genitals_ to mean the visible bits, too, but that goes for women as well (I wouldn't expect someone talking about _genitals_ to be referring to the cervix or the uterus, for instance). To refer unambiguously to both internal and external, I'd use _sex organ_ in normal speech (the uro-genital system including also other, non-reproductive bits). In more technical contexts, though, I'm pretty sure _genitals_ also refers to both internal and external.

Comment: @Janus: you would need a scalpel if you wanted to get to the prostate. Women have stuff that is not on the "outside," but is nevertheless accessible outside of a hospital.

Comment: Isn't  this question unclear and off-topic at best?

Comment: Men don't have a male equivalent of a *vulva* just as women don't have a female version of a *penis*. They're different things, folks. You might just as easily ask what is a catcher's mitt's version of a baseball bat.

Comment: @MishaRosnach [Not necessarily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostate_massage).

Comment: Whether they remain external depends on how cold it is.

Comment: @Josh61 As far as SWR go, this is quite valid; not looking for a synonym. It's clear and on-topic, it's just unnecessary (IMO) to have to make a distinction here. However that doesn't invalidate the question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I don't consider a prostate part of the genitals any more than an ovary is.  The polite word for a dude is "genitals."  It's not ambiguous.

Comment: @tchrist:  By that logic, you can get to almost any organ in the body without a scalpel.  The reason the internal/external female genitalia distinction is relevant is because it has evolved to be reached directly - not through a back door, and not through protective layers of skin and fascia.

Answer (score 1):

One needs a certain knowledge of embriology to answer this awkward question. As far back as I can remember, **the scrotum** (but not the testicles) is the male equivalent of the vulva, which consists of all the external female genitalia.  While the female embryo develops the vulva, the male embryo develops the scrotum at approximately the same time "in utero".  The ovaries being the testicles counterpart.

PS Since "vulva" belongs to technical vocabulary, I tried to use technical vocabulary in my answer instead of common parlance or slang-words. Now, if you are looking for a single word which includes the penis, scrotum and testicles, I'm afraid there isn't. Better use "the external male genitals" (or genitalia)

Comment: That doesn't fit with the common meaning of _vulva_ as ‘the external female genitals’, though, because the scrotum is only part of the external male genitals. I believe the answer is looking for a word that describes all the external male genitals, rather than a word for the structure that is biologically the male equivalent of the vulva in females. (Oh, you edited an address to that in as I was typing!)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  I've added something about that.

Comment: @sumelic The female urethral orifice isn't included in the genitals.  It's part of urinary tract. Then again, the labia majora (outer labia), the labia minora, the clitoris and the vaginal opening, are all part of the external female genitalia.

Comment: Thanks for not adding the obligatory illustrations in an effort to jack up your votes. :)